# Licensing system for client side code web application

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, cryptography

I have a client-side web application running on SharePoint Site Collection, each site collection has it's own unique id. I want to use a licensing process to lock the app to a site collection.

This is the challenge-response process I'm trying to implement:

- User prompted to generate `challenge code`
- `challenge code` is `site_collection_id` processed through some function
- User emails me `challenge code`
- Encrypt `challenge code` with a `private key`
- The encrypted result is considered the `license key` which I send to user
- User saves `license key` into the application

Validation Process:

- On app load, retrieve `license key`
- Decrypt `license key` using a `public key` stored in app
- The result is the `challenge code` the user had sent before
- Take that `challenge code` revert it back to a `site collection id`
- Retrieve the `site collection id` app is currently running on
- Compare the two to determine if `license key` is valid

Does this make sense? The one thing I'm not sure about is the public/private key stuff and if there's a way to do this in JavaScript.

---

I know it's impossible to 100% secure client-side applications. I'm just looking for something to prevent someone from **easily** distributing the application

Comment: This is probably better suited for [security.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use public/private key in javascript, I just used in my recent project. Check [openpgp.js](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs). The scenario you describe looks fine. You may also use daily tokens client will ask your server to be able to run, sharepoint site may send the token you give them back with a request for daily license, and you send license code and a token which is valid for 24h.

Comment: The token solution would be more secure but I'm looking for a solution that's completely isolated and doesn't require communication with external servers and generally more simple to maintain. opengp.js looks promising, I'll play around with it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: np, about openpgp.js, there are no much documentation samples around about it but it's easy to understand and it's really legit implementation. nice tool in the toolbox.

Comment: Actually probably can't use this unfortunately, the compatibility doesn't have high enough coverage. Explorer 11+ is what's supported but most of my users would be below that.

Comment: In this case you may try crypto.js (https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/). it's also good. openpgp.js requires ie11, because it uses browser's native webcrypto (which gives more reliable encryption, as it can produce random ntaively in OS, javascript's random function us in fact pseudo-random).

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it more. I have it in my project but I couldn't figure out how to do what I wanted to do with it or if what I was thinking even made sense

Comment: if your concern is only signing with private key and decrypt with public key, you may want to check http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/. and here is tutorial for signing:
https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-Signature-class

Comment: Awesome, ill go through it now and see if it works out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A classic setup involves publishing a freeware version, then unlocking it by validating the license key via AJAX and enabling the commercial functionality upon success:

> The configuration needs to include the license key, otherwise you will be seeing a Flowplayer text showing on top of the video. The installation happens between SCRIPT tags on your HTML page. The license key goes to the 3rd parameter of the flowplayer call, it's included in the flowplayer configuration object.

```
    flowplayer("player",
       "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.18.swf",{
// license key from your account
key: '#$7162d2d730cf607ac6d'
    });
```

> Note: When you deploy the commercial player inside an IFRAME you must choose the license key for the iframe's origin domain, i.e., the domain in the iframe's `src` attribute.

and a more modern alternative would be:

> If you want to host your own player library, you can find both your license key and latest JW Player files in your dashboard's Advanced Account page. Once downloaded, you will need to host jwplayer.js on your own server. When configuring your web page, you will then need to point to your copy of jwplayer.js and also define your self-hosted license key. Here's a code example:

```
<script src="//mywebsite.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js" ></script>
<script>jwplayer.key="ABCdeFG123456SeVenABCdeFG123456SeVen==";</script>
```

**References**

- [Flowplayer: Commerical Configuration](https://flowplayer.org/docs/setup.html#commercial-configuration)
- [JW Player: Embedding - host your own player library](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed)
- [Supporting Open Source Software Development in SSOs/SDOs](http://xml.coverpages.org/open-source/Open-Source-in-SSOs-SDOs.html)
- [Dev.Opera — Publishing Guidelines](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/publishing-guidelines/)